# How to get the key from value in redis and remove other key by checking its value?

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to maintain two collections.

> 1. The live or active servers. Say collection contains SERVER1,SERVER2.
> 2. The clients c1,c2,c3 connected to specific server say SERVER1 and clients c4,c5,c6 are connected to SERVER2  The other collections will
>      have,

```
**KEY : VALUE**
    c1:SERVER1
    c3:SERVER1
    c4:SERVER2
    c6:SERVER2
    c2:SERVER1
    c5:SERVER2
```

**The inactive servers I will remove from collections.**

whenever I'm removing a server (say SERVER1) from redis, I want to remove the instance whose values are matching with it. Here I want to remove c1,c2,c3 completely. Then collection will be like this:

```
**KEY : VALUE**
    c4:SERVER2
    c6:SERVER2
    c5:SERVER2
```

To maintain the collection, what type of redis command I can use. Like sets/lists.? 
How can I achieve this result.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the main list, you can just store them with `SET key val` command, or you could store them in a dedicated hash table with `HSET` (or `HMSET`). The later will give you the option to efficiently work with this table (especially if you have a large number of keys stored in your DB).

You would also want to keep a `SET` of connected clients to each server.
When you remove a server, remove all server set members from the main hash table and remove the set when done.

For your example:

```
   HMSET connectedClients c1 SERVER1 c2 SERVER1 c3 SERVER1 c4 SERVER2 c5 SERVER2 c6 SERVER2
   SADD SERVER1Clients c1 c2 c3
   SADD SERVER2Clients c4 c5 c6
```

when removing a server you can get all connected clients with 
`SMEMBERS SERVERxClients`, and remove the output list from the hash with 
`HDEL connectedClients <Output of SMEMBERS>`

Links to all of [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) and [set](http://redis.io/commands#set) commands documentation

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is 1. search what server a client is connecting to by checking its client id; 2. when a server is deleted, remove all the clients on this server.

I think you can store the client->server mapping by redis [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash), and use  redis [set](http://redis.io/commands#set) to store the clients of SERVER[x]

Use [sadd](http://redis.io/commands/sadd) to add clients to a server

And use [del](http://redis.io/commands/del) to completely remove a key of a server and its clients

Also, use redis pipeline to ensure the atomicity.

For example:

To add a client C to server[i]:

```
client.multi()
    .sadd("SERVER" + i, 'C')
    .hset('CLIENT_TO_SERVER', 'C', "SERVER" + i)
    .exec(function (err, replies) {
        console.log(replies)
    });
```

To delete a server[i]:

```
client.watch("SERVER" + i);
multi = client.multi();
client.smembers("SERVER" + i, function(err, replies) {
    var keys = Object.keys(replies)
    keys.forEach(function(i) {
        multi.hdel('CLIENT_TO_SERVER', keys[i])
    }
});
multi.del("SERVER"+i);
multi.exec(function(err,replies) {
    console.log(replies)
});
```

You can use `keys('SERVER*')` to get all the members in your first collection